# Invalid Json Primitive on Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I am posting my form using AJAX:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#Compare").click(function (e) {         
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_Compare","API")',
            dataType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                model: $("#CompareForm").serialize()
            },
            type: "post",
            success: function(response) {
                alert (response);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I am trying to deserialize my JSON result but I am getting an 'Invalid Json Primitive Exception'.

My Json Result:

```
"%5B0%5D.Id=1&%5B0%5D.Description=Sutherland+Silver+Plans+offers+you...&%5B0%5D.Price=30&%5B0%5D.Title=Silver+Plan&%5B0%5D.isSelected=true&%5B0%5D.isSelected=false&%5B1%5D.Id=2&%5B1%5D.Description=Sutherland+Gold+Plans+offers+you...&%5B1%5D.Price=50&%5B1%5D.Title=Gold+Plan&%5B1%5D.isSelected=true&%5B1%5D.isSelected=false&%5B2%5D.Id=3&%5B2%5D.Description=Sutherland+Platinum+Plans+offers+you...&%5B2%5D.Price=80&%5B2%5D.Title=Platinum+Plan&%5B2%5D.isSelected=false"
```

Comment: $("#CompareForm").serialize() is returns this result only any other solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem confused about what JSON is, and whether the issue is with the request or the response.

The issue is with the *request*. You are attempting to put the querystring that `serialize()` creates in to the `model` parameter of an object, which itself will be serialised and encoded again. Instead, just pass the querystring that serialise generates to the action:

```
$("#Compare").click(function (e) {         
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("_Compare","API")',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        data: $("#CompareForm").serialize(),
        type: "post",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You have specified the response will be JSON. If this is the case, use `console.log` to inspect it, otherwise the `alert()` will only show `[object Object]`.

Comment: I tried JSON.Stringify(object) as well same result.

"&%5B0%5D"  was appending before each and every key.

Comment: Yes I tried same result, my problem is instead of model name i am getiing  "%5B0%5D"